# Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength failing randomly

Tags: java, cryptography, jce

I'm facing a rather strange behavior about decrypting in Java. Using the code below

```
public void decrypt(File file, String output_file_path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    String hex_enc_key = "346a23652a46392b4d73257c67317e352e3372482177652c";
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(HexParser.fromHexString(hex_enc_key), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(output_file_path)), cipher);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    doCopy(fis, cos);
}
```

I get *random* exceptions

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters

I googled the issue and found out about [JCE unlimited strength](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html), but I can't understand why I get those random exceptions even if I'm always using the *same* key (sometimes it works and sometimes not, based on the input file I need to decrypt).

For the sake of clarity I'm using

```
Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES")
```

to check for JCE limitations, and have no issue whatsoever encrypting with the same settings:

```
public void encrypt(File file, String output_file_path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); 
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(HexParser.fromHexString(db_enc_key), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), cipher);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(output_file_path));
    doCopy(cis, os);
    cis.close();
    os.close();
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot, nicola

Comment: ECB mode is not secure.  http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html

Comment: Are you running this on multiple computers?

Comment: @SLaks: it's a proof of concept for a third party app (whatsapp) so I can't change the encryption

Comment: @Antimony: yes that's my target otherwise I would have solved the issue installing JCE on the server

Comment: ...and are you consistently getting this exception on some computers and not on others?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen no I'm getting the same behavior (exception) for the same files on all the computers, but I can't understand why when I'm using the same key for all of them (I mean: if the key is too long it should throw exception on all of them, right?). The only thing that change is the encrypted file (i was even thinking about some encryption padding problem)

Comment: Have you checked your HexParser.fromHexString method / class? Does it return the same byte array each time? The only thing I can think of is maybe the class has edge cases or other issues that means it's returning inconsistent results. 
When the string is being changed to a byte array do you specify encoding? i.e. string.getBytes("UTF-8")? 
You can check the byte array it returns against DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(string), which is in javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter